# How can I create a function that wraps a value between a minimum and maximum in a cyclic natutre?

Tags: python, math

I have a function for mapping a value to between -180 and 180:

```
min_ = -180
max_ = 180
range_ = (max_ - min_)

def min_max_map(value):
    return (value + max_) % range_ - range_/2

print(min_max_map(200)) # -160
print(min_max_map(200 + 360)) # -160 again
```

However when I want to shift over the minimum and maximum bounds the answer is wrong:

```
min_ = -180 - 360
max_ = 180 - 360
range_ = (max_ - min_)

def min_max_map(value):
    return (value + max_) % range_ - range_/2

print(min_max_map(200)) # -160 rather than -160 - 360 = -520
```

I can't work out how to fix my formula. How can I generalize my formula to map any minimum and maximum values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def min_max_map(value):
    return (value - min_) % range_ + min_
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept after 5 minutes!

Comment: @TomMcLean Note that this formula can produce a result equal to `min_`, but can never produce a result equal to `max_`. Which might or might not be what you intended. At least it is consistent with python's builtin `range` function; and it is consistent with your `-180` to `+180` example (an oriented angle of -180° is the same as an oriented angle of +180°).

Comment: @Stef Thanks for the warning, I will test my program and make sure that that is okay!

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the python built-in `min` and `max` functions? Something like:

```
return min( 180, max( -180, value ) )
```

Comment: This is clipping, not wrapping.

Comment: ah, missed that ;)